# output returns nothing when running script

Tags: bash, solaris

When I run this script I get nothing returned.  Any suggestions?  Here is the code.

```
securityTlsVersion() {
     local file="/usr/lib/firefox/mozilla.cfg"
     local config=`more $file|grep security.tls.version.max`
     local tlsmax="lockPref(\"security.tls.version.max`
     if [ "`hostname`" == "server1" ] || [ "`hostname`" == "server2" ];then
       if [ "$config" = "" ]; then
         echo "Adding security.tls.version.max line to mozilla.cfg"
         echo "tlsmax >> $file
         echo "security.tls.version.max is now configured"
       else
         echo "security.tls.version.max is already configured"
       fi
     fi
 }
```

Comment: Help other users trying to answer your question by pointing out what you want to accomplish and what you expect from the code.

Comment: Please use code formatting on your source code.  You can add the code formatting using the `{}` button on the edit window.

Comment: I'm guessing this line is wrong: local **tlsmax="lockPref(\"security.tls.version.max`** Unmatched backtick and unmatched double quote.  Your first `If` looks fine as long as you are running this script on a computer with a hostname of `server1` and `server2`

Comment: BTW, it looks like there's no particular point to `more` here. `config=$(grep security.tls.version.max <"$file")` would be better form. (Note that the `local` definitions should be on their own line; you can put `local file config tlsmax` up at the top of the function -- that way `local` doesn't shadow the exit status of the commands you run for the assignment).

Comment: Also, you almost certainly want to `echo "$tlsmax"`, not `echo "tlsmax"`. And note that `==` isn't guaranteed to work portably inside `[ ]` -- the only POSIX-standardized string comparison operator is `=`.

Comment: Using `$(...)` is also much better form than backticks -- it nests better, avoids changing the meaning and behavior of backslashes, and is guaranteed to be present for any POSIX-compliant (which is to say, post-1992) shell.

Answer (score 0):

There is below the result of `shellcheck`. It means the first lines contain unclosed `"`. As @JNevill wrote, this is the line starting with `local tlsmax`:

```
shellcheck myscript.sh 

In myscript.sh line 7:
     if [ "`hostname`" == "server1" ] || [ "`hostname`" == "server2" ];then
        ^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this test expression.
          ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this double quoted string.
           ^-- SC1072: Expected end of double quoted string. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

Does it help you?